# Finding MST with Prim's Algorithm Java

Tags: java, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

Currently I am trying to find the minimum spanning tree using Prim's algorithm. I have a program created that creates a Weighted matrix that I need to use. My new program should take the WeightedGraph and return a list/array of the edges based on the indices. My question is how would I go about finding the minimum spanning tree using this function -- public int[][] prim(WeightedGraph graph) { --

```
package WeightGraph;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WeightedGraph {

    private int[][] weightMatrix;
    private int size;
    private String[] nodes;

    public WeightedGraph(String filename){


        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            String line = sc.nextLine();
            nodes = line.split(",");
            size = nodes.length;

            weightMatrix = new int[size][size];  

            // fill matrix
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                    if(i == j){
                        weightMatrix[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        weightMatrix[i][j] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            while(sc.hasNext()){
                String let1 = sc.nextLine();
                String[] entryNum = let1.split(",");
                String lett1 = entryNum[0];
                String lett2 = entryNum[1];
                int letter1 = Arrays.asList(nodes).indexOf(lett1);
                int letter2 = Arrays.asList(nodes).indexOf(lett2);
                int weight = Integer.parseInt(entryNum[2]);
                weightMatrix[letter1][letter2] = weight;
                weightMatrix[letter2][letter1] = weight;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception FileNotFoundException)
        {
           System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }
    }

    public int getDistance(int i,int k)
    {
       if(i>=0 && i<size && k>=0 && k<size)
           return weightMatrix[i][k];
       else return -1;
    }

    public boolean directLink(int i,int k)
    {
        if(i>=0 && i<size && k>=0 && k<size)
            return (weightMatrix[i][k]!=-1);
        else return false;
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
       return size;
    }

    public String getNodeName(int i) {
        return nodes[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @JorisKinable Sorry I probably should've asked an actual question with this. Basically I need to find the minimum spanning tree using Prim's algorithm and I'm not sure how to start it. How would I go about finding the mst using this function '''public int[][] prim(WeightedGraph graph) {'''

Comment: The WeightedGraph takes in this .txt file                                                                  a,b,c,d,e,f,g
a,b,3
a,c,2
a,e,1
b,d,1
b,e,5
b,f,5
c,e,5
d,f,5
e,f,4
e,g,3
g,a,1                                                                                                                                                         But the prim function would only take the WeightedGraph graph as its input.

Comment: There are plenty of sources which explain how to implement Prim's spanning tree algorithm, See e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-greedy-algo-5/
Please revise your post and state your question explicitly. Also show what you have done so far and where you are stuck.